# Locking entities or DB on JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Does the JPA method [EntityManager#lock](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#lock-java.lang.Object-javax.persistence.LockModeType-) take immediate effect on the in-memory managed entity instances or just route the semantics on-demand to the DB?

Comment: You linked to the docs, which has a link to the LockModeType which describes it for you: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/LockModeType.html  As it states, what happens depends on the lock type used and your object if it has optimistic version locking or not.

Comment: Yes, I guess so, but it's somehow vague to comprehend. Could you help elaborate the following scenarios? (a) Entity locked but DB not; (b) DB locked but Entity not; (c) Both locked; and (d) Both not.

Comment: There really isn't any locking that doesn't involve the database, but I can't explain it better without a more concrete example or situation.  Does your entity have optimistic locking, and what LockModeType are you looking at?    Optimistic locking uses a version field within the object itself, and will update it, but it is transactional.  It prevents problems by making the current transaction fail if its been updated out from under it, under the optimistic assumption that this isn't likely to occur.  Pessimistic locking generally locks the row using database select for update semantics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locking using [EntityManager#lock](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#lock-java.lang.Object-javax.persistence.LockModeType-) is immediate only if you use one of **pessimistic** lock types.

Using a pessimistic lock type routes lock instruction to the DB and waits until either lock succeeds or a timeout is reached. Therefore the call is blocking and if not successful, transaction is rolled back.

The immediate effect on in-memory objects is then indirect, but **immediate** - if lock is not obtained, transaction is rolled back and it is not possible to successfully finish the transaction. It makes no sense to modify entity objects after this, as they will not be persisted. But in theory, it is possible to modify and work with the entity object as with any other plain Java object, provided that you catch LockTimeoutException, but I do not recommend this.

If you use **optimistic** locking, then from the nature of it, the transaction is rolled back only after a collision is detected. This can happen only **at the moment an entity would be persisted into the DB** (typically at the end of transaction, but also can happen during intermediate flush). The point of optimistic locking is to deffer locking at a later moment when it is obvious that a collision had occurred.

Very nice documentation about JPA locking mechanism can be found in this [Locking in JPA](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/lock) page.